# Percentage of played game sessions by RPG?

Tags: statistics, online-roleplaying, roll20, fantasy-grounds

A few months ago, I saw a pie chart with the percentages of games played on Roll20 or Fantasy Grounds (a virtual tabletop system), with a count of sessions played per RPG.

Does anyone know a source for these graphs? I'm mainly looking to compare time periods to see changes to distribution over time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this? http://www.enworld.org/forum/content.php?3134-Which-Games-Were-Most-Played-On-FANTASY-GROUNDS-In-2015-(Hint-D-D!)#.WGRcqrGZMy4

Or there's the Quarterly [Orr Group Industry Report](http://blog.roll20.net/post/152869666945/the-orr-group-industry-report-q3-2016) published on the Roll20 blog, which offers a list of games and players on Roll20 for a given quarter (the link is to the 2016/Q3 report). Not broken down by session though.

Comment: That's it! And the Orr Group report is an extra bonus, many thanks.